# How do I fix dead Synaptics ClickPad on Ubuntu 12.10 + Toshiba P850?

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, synaptics

I've recently purchased a Toshiba Laptop having Windows 8 installed. After successfully dual booting in this EFI madness Win8/Ubuntu 12.10 I am at a loss as to how to enable the touch pad in Ubuntu 12.10.

Problem (Concise description)

- Toshiba Satellite P850 (new)
- Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome (latest)
- Synaptics Multitouch
- Touch Pad dead, no response from any stimulus.

  - Works in DOZ8

Current Work-Around: I am using an USB Mouse

Here are some helpful information regarding the computer / logs / and so forth.
Relevant Info from various debug efforts

Verify type of device:

```
egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

Suspect driver missing, executing command to install shows this is not the case

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

Dump of Xorg.0.log

```
[    21.804] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event9)
[    21.804] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[    21.804] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    21.804] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    21.804] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    21.804] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    21.804] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    21.804]    compiled for 1.12.99.905, module version = 1.6.2
[    21.804]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    21.804]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 18.0
[    21.804] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    21.804] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    21.804] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[    21.808] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5678
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4732
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[    21.808] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    21.808] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    21.808] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input9/event9"
[    21.808] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[    21.808] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    21.808] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    21.808] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: AccelFactor is now 0.037
[    21.808] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    21.808] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    21.808] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    21.808] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    21.808] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    21.809] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    21.809] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    21.810] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Toshiba input device (/dev/input/event6)
```

Found some info in ArchLinux regarding the driver being loaded twice with the second instance killing the driver.  Forgot the link.  They were messing with Xorg.conf

Checking with command

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             32688  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
rfcomm                 46619  0 
bnep                   18140  2 
bluetooth             209199  10 rfcomm,bnep
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77876  1 
joydev                 17457  0 
coretemp               13400  0 
kvm_intel             132759  0 
snd_hda_intel          33491  3 
snd_hda_codec         134212  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm                   414070  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13180  0 
snd_pcm                96580  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               76749  0 
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
aesni_intel            51037  0 
cryptd                 20403  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
aes_x86_64             17208  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61521  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ath9k                 131308  0 
microcode              22803  0 
psmouse                95552  0 
i915                  520519  3 
mac80211              539908  1 ath9k
serio_raw              13215  0 
ath9k_common           14055  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              395218  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    23827  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
drm_kms_helper         46784  1 i915
drm                   275528  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei                    40690  0 
cfg80211              206566  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd                    78734  16     snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
lpc_ich                17061  0 
soundcore              15047  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
toshiba_acpi           18726  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    19070  1 toshiba_acpi
mac_hid                13205  0 
video                  19335  1 i915
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_logitech           26585  0 
ff_memless             13013  1 hid_logitech
usbhid                 46947  1 hid_logitech
hid                   100366  2 hid_logitech,usbhid
r8169                  61650  0
```

And for good measure

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

If I am interpreting this correctly, wasn't the driver supposed to show up?

Found http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/02/call-for-testing-clickpad.html

executing xinput

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Did not execute instructions as it is for 12.04 / am running 12.10 due to concerns issuing dist_upgrade which I think would roll me back to 12.04

Tags for relevant info seem to be google “cft clickpad support ubuntu”

Main fix appears to be the kernel does not recognize the click pad.  I am confused as it is reported properly and seemingly loads the driver per Xorg.0.log yet if I am correct, the module is not loaded per lsmod command.

Comment: No **event13** listed in /dev/input/

Comment: **mouse1** exists in /dev/input/ ---> Is **mouse1** alias for **event13**

Comment: http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html

Comment: Above link suggests issue with synaptics 50 xorg file

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but this issue occurred on my Toshiba Satellite C660 this afternoon and I just fixed it.

Enter BIOS: F2 on boot
F9 to restore default settings
Change any settings back to how you adapted them (if at all)
Exit Saving Changes

Worked for me first time, hope this helps any people suffering with this problem still.

My symptoms were a completely dead touchpad - others having reported only basic touchpad features e.g. no tap to click, two finger scrolling etc. So, perhaps this could solve the issue of the latter too.

Answer (score 1):

I have a P850

This is WORKED for me:

1. Turned off , unplugged ,take out battery
2. hold down power button for 2mins
3. put everything back, power on.
4. Smile.

Also it is a good idea to update your bios.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion on http://who-t.blogspot.nl/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html helped for me (on an Asus A53S).

I copied `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` and uncommented the `MatchDevicePath` line, as in:

```
   Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "touchpad catchall"
       Driver "synaptics"
       MatchIsTouchpad "on"
       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
   EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on the same laptop.  I verified the O/S recognized my touchpad by going to a terminal and entering the `xinput` command - the list includes **SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad**.  I tried to watch the pointer variables by typing `synclient -m 100` but nothing was happening.

I felt there was a hardware lock on the touchpad, but I couldn't figure out how to disable it.  My laptop has no switches on it, and the `fn-f5` combination wasn't doing anything in ubuntu.

To fix, I booted a Windows install stick and noticed that my touchpad was still unresponsive.  Still in the first screen of Windows setup I hit `fn-f5` and then the pointer became responsive.  Quit Windows, and reboot into Ubuntu and my pointer still works (gestures and all).