# The touchpad on Dell XPS 9550 is not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, synaptics, 18.04, xps

I've freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 9550, but the touchpad is not working at all.

From what I've read most of the time installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and rebooting the machine should fix the problem, but not on my end.

I've also tried `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` with no luck.

When I go to Settings/Devices/Mouse & Touchpad I can clearly see there are options for touchpad.

This is the result of running `xinput --list`

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

I'm out of options, so I'll appreciate If someone could help out or suggest something that I haven't tried yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and adding the nomodeset and acpi_rev_override parameters to the kernel parameter solved it.
You just have to add this line before booting:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_rev_override=1 nomodeset"
I had a lot of trouble with 18.04 so I went back to 17.10.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, but that didn't help either.

I've booted up the Ubuntu today and now right after I enter my password  and I see the desktop, everything freezes - no keyboard, no mouse, no touchpad, nothing... I must point out that this is not a result from changing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, but I don't know how that happened... I'll probably switch to different version like you've suggested 17.11 or into completely different OS/distro. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my touchpad was completely dead. After searching a lot and trying different things I've found an answer in this thread that worked for me [Touchpad won't work after Ubuntu 14.04 install on Toshiba Satellite S55-B5266 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602147/touchpad-wont-work-after-ubuntu-14-04-install-on-toshiba-satellite-s55-b5266-la)

> Restart your laptop and while restarting press Fn+F2 to enter into BIOS and press Fn+F5 in order to refresh the hardware settings (although you cant see the BIOS getting refreshed). That's it and now just save and exit from BIOS and your touchpad starts working.

My laptop is a Toshiba, but I hope it may work for you aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the machine to the latest bios, 1.8.0. It was released on the 14th of August, [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/it/it/itbsdt1/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/drivers).